# How Connect cmdlet generating by autorest.powershell?

Tags: powershell, swagger, autorest

I used [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/main/docs/introduction.md) to create a Powershell CLI for my Rest API using its swagger. I want to have a connect function to get the server address (host) and save it for later commands like an open session. It's nice to check the server availability in the connect function as well.

Is there anything like this in the generated CLI? If not, how can I add this functionality to it?

For example I want to something like below

```
Connect-FooService -Host foo.net -Port 443
Get-FooSome # automatically use above information (or session) and connect to Foo service
```